# php preg_split(). Not the right pattern and converts period to comma?

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I've got a question. I want to scale some CSS values I've got stored in values. (simplified) I've made a function to scale them up.

Two things I don't get right.

- The pattern, it looks like it only splits one character and not the rest
- It looks likes it converts the period it finds to a comma??

```
$string = '0.3rem';
$scale = 1.5;
echo calcCssNewValue( $string, $scale ); 

function calcCssNewValue( $string, $scale ){

    $stringArray = preg_split('/[a-zA-Z]*/', $string, 2, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

    if (  count( $stringArray ) == 1 ) {
        $returnVal = (  $stringArray[0] * $scale) ;
    } else {
        $returnVal = ( $stringArray[0] * $scale) . $stringArray[1];
    }

    return $returnVal;
}
```

`result: '0,45em' expected: '0.45rem'` Note it's missing the `r` and has a comma instead of a period.

Where did I go wrong? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest part of the solution is from @Rarst [in this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54774991/7295693)

I've ended up with this code:

```
function calcCssNewValue( $string, $scale ){

    $stringArray = preg_split( '/([a-zA-Z]+)/', $string, 2, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY );

    $returnVal = number_format( (  $stringArray[0] * $scale ), 2, '.', ''); ;

    if (  count( $stringArray ) > 1 ) {

        $returnVal .= $stringArray[1];
    }

    return $returnVal;

}
```

The `$stringArray` is by @Rarst.

The `$returnVal` I've added `number_format()`. And forced the decimal point to an actual point. Somehow, and I don't know why, it changed the decimal point to a comma. But only when doing math...

Answer (score 3):

I don't get same result running your code, the split results for me in array of empty string and original value. `*` is probably the problem since it's matching *zero* matches of the pattern.

So not sure about comma thing either since I don't see it.

I would adjust your split like this, seems to get it done:

```php
$stringArray = preg_split( '/([a-zA-Z]+)/', $string, 2, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY );
```

This requires:

- pattern to match *at least* one time
- wrapping it in `()` makes delimiter capture work since it only applies to that
- adding no empty drops lingering empty item (pattern doesn't seem to count against limit of two)

Comment: If you added an explanation of what you changed in the regex this would be more helpful. Also since at most two values from the array are used, you don't really need the `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY`

Comment: @Nick it seems you _do_ need that with capturing delimiter, I am guessing it doesn't count against the limit of two (so you get (1) number (2) delimiter (3) empty trailing string). I mean that can be ignored, but not... tidy. :)

Comment: On balance you're probably right, it could cause unexpected results if the following code was changed at all. Anyway, good explanation now +1

Comment: @Rarst, thank you. That did the trick for the letter part in the problem. And a nice explanation as well